# Margins in jquery-mobile page

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

how can I put margin in the left and right of the whole page using css?

I tried in various ways but I am not able to do: jsfiddle.net/1dsvfudq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it right, you just missed commas:

```
.ui-header, .ui-footer, .ui-content {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Add them and margins will emerge )